# UrlHelper.Action("Edit", "Ad") returns id parameter?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, action

**Hi,**

I am using the following code to generate a URL :

```
UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
urlHelper.Action("Edit", "Ad");
```

If Im currently is on URL http://localhost:16055/Ad/Edit/87 the Action method will return : "/Ad/Edit/87" ?

Why? I thought that urlHelper.Action("Edit", "Ad") would in this satet not include any parameters?

**BestRegards**

**Edit 1:**  (routs)

```
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Ad", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "TreeEditing", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{name}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "AdCategory", action = "Add", name = string.Empty, id = -1 }
    );
```

Comment: It takes into account the current request context, and the routing for the given action/controller.  I'm pretty sure (but not 100%) that if you specify your own route value dictionary, you can control this behavior. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470197.aspx

Comment: Okay? But how do I do to ignore the current context as easy as possible? Is it possible to do this without creating new rout?

Comment: Darin Dimitrov (Who is amazing btw) posted an example of what I was trying to show you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I thought that urlHelper.Action("Edit", "Ad") would in this satet not include any parameters?

Well, you thought wrong. All url helpers automatically include all arguments that were part of the original request. So if you had an id route parameter present, its value will be reused.

If you don't want this behavior you will have to explicitly set the values for those parameters:

```
var action = urlHelper.Action("Edit", "Ad", new { id = "" });
```

Comment: Thanks, this does solve the problem. but what happens if a new parameters is added to this URL then I would have to include this to action action as "". On a big site this could be a mess. Is there no simplier way to just ignora all parameters? All I want is to generate a URL to the stated action.

Comment: @SnowJim, that's how standard url helpers work and this is by design. If you don't like this behavior you will have to roll your own custom url helpers.

Comment: A way to partially mitigate this is that it only includes parameters that are part of the route; so you'll only have to clear parameters that are part of both the current page and the route you're creating a link for.

Comment: Thanks! _"All url helpers automatically include all arguments that were part of the original request. "_ that's a "nice" scarcely-to-undocumented feature. :(