# ASP MVC 3 Routes bug?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I discovered a defect on my website ... and I am not sure if it is a bug ... or it is by design.

I have the following route registered.

```
routes.MapRoute("EditProduct", // Route name
                "product/addproduct/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Product", action = "AddProduct", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
                );
```

In _Layout.cshtml I have the following link defined:

```
  <li><a href="@Url.Action( "AddProduct", "Product")">Add new product</a></li>
```

If the current url contains the 'Id' parameter, for example: /product/details/5, the menu link from layout is generated /product/addproduct/5. It is taking the id parameter from RequestContext.

Is this a bug ... since in the helper I do not specify the parameters for my link? ... or this is by design?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is by design.

Comment: Same question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6690372/1081079

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472009/urlhelper-actionedit-ad-returns-id-parameter

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you even need to specify a route here.

By default MVC3 uses the URL `/Controller/Action/{id}`.

Try removing your specified route and see if it works without.